# 100% width div grid

Tags: html, css, grid, row

I have 160 images I want to align in a grid that takes up the entire 100% width of the web page.

I can not for the life of me figure out how to do this so that the each row stays connected to each other. Could anyone help me out?

[image]

This is where I am at for each row. But when I add another row, the rows don't stay together.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:50px;display:table;">
   <div style="display:table-row;">
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;width:6.25%;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you are going over 100%... You need to split 100% into 160 images... meaning the percent you should be using is .625, not 6.25. Is that the problem?

Comment: @buddhistBeast 6.25*16 is 100% so I'm not going over but that's not the problem. My problem is keeping the rows together. And keeping the height consistent

Comment: Check this JsFiddle out... As far as I know it should be working just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/9RqY4/2/ Another thing you should do is to make your height much larger or else the rows wont stay current with one another.

Comment: Just curious... Why not use an actual table for this? I know people rag on them all the time, but it is probably the easiest way to align things in a grid like this... http://jsfiddle.net/yvR9W/

Comment: Read this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: @BuddhistBeast While I agree with the link you posted, I feel that it was directed toward layouts that are not a specific grid like OP illustrated above. Also, the majority of the arguments, both for and against tables, are primarily based on opinion. If all OP is trying to accomplish is a 16x10 grid, then I don't see why a table is _that_ big of a sin. :)

Comment: @DrydenLong is right. The bottom line is that tables are for tabular data - and this is clearly a table ;)